# Как удалить неиспользуемые пакеты node.js?

Tags: node.js

Недавно начал осваивать *node.js*
Устанавливал кучу пакетов, вот уже накопилось много.
Удалять вручную боюсь. Как бы не удалить нужное.

Comment: Что и куда установил?

Comment: Найди эту папку и удали ее... Если глобально ставил, то лежит там где по умолчанию устанавливаются пакеты для NODEJS в папке node_modules. Если локально то в папке с проектом в папке node_modules.... И удали из  package.json, что-бы случайно не установить

Comment: Да дело не как удалить, а найти не используемые

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/232908

Answer (score 0):

Вот ссылка на статью, где детально описано процес удаления неиспользуемых пакетов `node.js` - [клик](https://dev.to/poopcoder/remove-unused-npm-modules-from-package-json-2e7i)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Удаляй все. Нужные поставятся заново